# Android sending notifications on time with unique text

Tags: android, push-notification, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, alarm

I am making an app in android which should work like a simple task reminder app.
My problem is that I want the app to send notification to the user if a before choosentime is up. I am working with the `BroadcastReceiver` and the `AlarmManager` to schedule the alarm. I know that i have to set the notification/ and alarm_id unique but i don't know how to send multiple notifications with specific title and text. So the title should be the name of the task which is saved in a SQL database.
I tried to set up the variables as static but that doesn't help me because it will change all notifications to the same text.
That's my broadcast receiver ->

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

private Context context;



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    this.context = context;
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
    createNotification("Title", "Message", "Time is up");

    Log.d("AlertReceiver", "Extra: " + title);
}







private void createNotification(String title, String message, String ticker)
{
    PendingIntent notificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, NavigationActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notificationIntent);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_access_alarms_white_24dp);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    mBuilder.setTicker(ticker);

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify((int)System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());


}
}
```

Hope anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually i have found an answer. That is also an answer to the people who asked how to access the variables in an broadcastreceiver. 
When you create the alarm you have to set up an Intent which will be started if the alarm goes off

```
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, receiver.getClass());
        alertIntent.putExtra("Notification_ID", taskID);
        Log.d("AlertIntent", "ID" + String.valueOf(alertIntent.getIntExtra("Notification_ID", 0)));

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alertIntent.getIntExtra("Notification_ID", 0), alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Here you can set an extra to your intent which will always be unique because you will always create a new one. 
In your Broadcastreceiver class you can then get the extra with

```
int taskID = alarmIntent.getIntExtra("Notification_ID", 1);
```

Hope this answer is useful to someone.